# Batch script to open multiple programs + multiple browser tabs

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation

Disclaimers: I don't program for work, and my skills in reading code are at a beginner level

I found a helpful script to open multiple tabs (in Chrome) from an initial script. I wanted to open multiple applications as well (example has OneNote and Outlook).
* The 'list.txt' file that this calls just contains four different urls.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set num=4
for /l %%i in (1,1,%num%) do call :start
endlocal
goto :eof

:start
set /p URL=<list.txt
start "" "%URL%"
more +1 list.txt | findstr /r /v "^$" > tmp_list.txt
echo.%URL%>>tmp_list.txt
del list.txt
ren tmp_list.txt list.txt

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ONENOTE.EXE"
start ONENOTE.EXE

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE"
start OUTLOOK.EXE

goto :eof
```

I think I understand how the browser tabs code works, but I suspect that that logic is interfering with opening Outlook and OneNote, and therefore every time I run this script, multiple instances of Outlook and OneNote open up.

Any help is much appreciated, as it's always a good idea to try automating the repetitive admin work.

Comment: Scripts run from the top down and don't jump to other places in the script unless you tell them to do so. Think about where OneNote and Outlook are currently being started and why they're each opening four times, then think about where those lines would have to be if you only wanted to open them once.

Comment: Have you ever thought about using `Powershell` and the command `Start-Process`, which allows you to open multiple apps and tabs in browser ?

Comment: Why are you not using a FOR /F command to read the list? I have never seen such a convoluted piece of code to read a file.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set "num=4"
( for /l %%i in (1, 1, %num%) do call :start ) < list.txt

cd /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16"
start ONENOTE.EXE
start OUTLOOK.EXE

endlocal
exit /b

:start
set /p "URL="
start "" "%URL%"
exit /b
```

If you enclose the `for` loop in parentheses and stdin with list.txt,
then the file handle remains open so that each of the 4 lines is read
in sequence.
Your posted code reopens the file handle with each loop so you get the
1st line read with each call.

**Summary**:

The `for` loop reads each of the 4 lines from list.txt.
`call :start` accepts the stdin of a line in which `set /p "URL="`
stores the line in the variable named `URL`. `start` opens the
value of `%URL%`. The call will return to the line called from
and will loop again.

When the loop completes, Onenote executes and then Outlook executes.